# show modal dialog on asp.net i giving the stack overflow error

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to open modal dialog from asp.net when i click on hyperlink field in gridview. But I am getting the error "stackoverflow at line 662". Please let me know where am I doing wrong.

My code below...

```
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ControlStyle-Width="30px" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="#003759">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkURLgoogle" runat="server" ImageUrl="/_layouts/myproject/Styles/image.png"
                                          ToolTip="Link to google" NavigateUrl="javascript:window.ShowDialog('http://www.google.com','','width=500,height=500')">
        </asp:HyperLink>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Thanks.

Comment: can you locate the `stackoverflow at line 662"` ?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue by putting everything in the function and calling that function from navigateurl.